# Draw a normal from a point to a line

Tags: shapely, python-2.7, python-3

How to draw a [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) LineString (AB) to existing LineString (CDEF) from a given Point (A)?
[image: normal AB]

**Shapely version == 1.5.16**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a method that will extend the line if required (see boxes in example screenshots) to guarantee a 90 degree angle.  It is based on the following answer which contains full details of the working.

[Projection of a point to a line segment Python Shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49073142/737471)

```py
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

points = [Point(4.5, 1.5), Point(4.5, 1.5), Point(1.95, 2.35), Point(11.78, -1.38), Point(9.32, -0.02), Point(0.95, 0.94)]
line = LineString(((0.5, 0.0), (2.5, 1.0), (7.0, 1.25), (10, -2.0)))

# Explode line segments
lines = []
for c1, c2 in zip(line.coords, line.coords[1:]):
    lines.append(LineString([c1, c2]))

for point in points:
    # get closest line segment
    distances = [segment.distance(point) for segment in lines]
    nearest_line = lines[distances.index(min(distances))]

    x = np.array(point.coords[0])

    u = np.array(nearest_line.coords[0])
    v = np.array(nearest_line.coords[len(nearest_line.coords) - 1])

    n = v - u
    n /= np.linalg.norm(n, 2)

    p = u + n * np.dot(x - u, n)

    l = LineString([point, Point(p)])

    # If you want to see which actually intersect
    # if l.intersects(nearest_line.buffer(1e-05)):  # Use buffer to handle floating point imprecision
        # do something...
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 layers:
a point layer, a line layer.

[image]

1/I explode the line (see qgis menu) so as to be able to select each segment of the polyline.
[image]

2/ from the pt layer, from the geometry command by expression (see qgis menu) I write the following line:

`shortest_line($geometry, aggregate('Explose', 'collect', $geometry))`

[image]

Comment: This doesn't guarantee 90 degrees. E.g. imagine if the top-most polyline were tilted at 45 degrees instead of approximately flat, as you've shown.